# Why 4204900352 & 4204904447 is -90066944?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to do some bitwise operations with javascript but it gives wrong answer.

```
4204900352 & 4204904447
```

Is there anyway to fix this ?

Comment: what is the *right* answer?

Comment: The *right* answer in JS would in fact be exactly -90066944

Comment: python gives 4204900352 as answer

Comment: Javascript doesn't, but you're right, the correct answer should be `4204900352`, or `11111010101000011011000000000000`

Comment: They're different interpretations of the same 32 bits, one unsigned and one signed two's complement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript bitwise AND operator works on *signed* 32 bit integers, in your case `-90066944` and `-90062849`. The result `-90066944` is the correct answer, and there's no way to fix that.

You can cast the result to an unsigned 32 bit integer using the unsigned bit shift operator though:

```
(4204900352 & 4204904447) >>> 0 // 4204900352
```

Of course it won't work for than 32 bits either, you'll need to handcraft a solution (or wait for [BigInt](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-bigint/)) for that.

Answer (score 2):

Your numbers are negative numbers when thought of as 32-bit signed integer values. JavaScript bitwise operations are carried out with 32-bit precision, and both those values have `1` in the uppermost bit position.

You can use this trick:

```
var x = 4204900352 & 4204904447;
if (x < 0) x += Math.pow(2, 32);
```

Comment: Claming that the numbers are *negative* is inaccurate, as they are definitely positive, but 64-bit floating point numbers instead of 32-bit signed integers (to which they are cast during bitwise operations, which makes them negative).

Comment: @Frxstrem well they're negative when examined by signed 32-bit integer math, which is what's going on here. I think we're in agreement. :) Editing for clarity.

Comment: No, they aren't negative.  What's happening is JS stores them as 64-bit, and when it does so, all of the left bits are 0 for both numbers.  e.g. the first number becomes `00 00 00 00 FA A1 B0 00`.   Well if they both have the same leading bits, the AND result is 1.  Thus causing results leading bits to all by 1s.  Hence, negative.

Comment: Well think about it however you want; 32-bit operator results with the high bit set will end up as negative numbers.